# MobileOrg synchronization(pull)

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have just started to use OrgMobile. Its really good about planning day. System is work really good about synchronization Computer to Phone(`org-mobile-push`) (Computer ----> Dropbox ---->Phone ✔). But when I change something from my phone and when I wanted to synchronize it from phone (`org-mobile-pull`) (Phone --- > Dropbox ---> Computer ☹) it makes problem.

For ex:
My org file OrgCapture.org (which is added with `org-agenda-file-to-front`)

```
#+LAST_MOBILE_CHANGE: 2015-05-21 21:55:50
* TODO from computer 1
  :PROPERTIES:
  :ID:       348a58d3-243a-41ac-aa9a-ae1bdd403e38
  :END:
* TODO from computer 2
  :PROPERTIES:
  :ID:       7eb71e7f-aa19-4c7c-84ad-76641d1aba19
  :END:
```

### I can see that file after push from my phone there is no problem

- **!!** When I add some notes from Android Phone and pull from computer

Messages board
0 new, 1 edits, 0 flags, 1 errors

the file that just affected is **flagged.org**

```
* Not on a heading F(edit:addheadıng) [[olp:OrgCapture.org][OrgCapture.org]]
** Old value

** New value
TODO Phone 
[2015-05-21 Per 21:54]
** End of edit
```

In conclusion:
There is no any changes in OrgCapture.org (except #+LAST_MOBILE_CHANGE: 2015-05-21 21:55:50)
If I push again from my computer also everything disappear what I change from phone

### Some technical information about my system

My Init file

```
;; mobileOrg
(require 'org-install)
(require 'org-mobile)
;; Set to the location of your Org files on your local system
(setq org-directory "~/org")
;; Set to the name of the file where new notes will be stored
(setq org-mobile-inbox-for-pull "~/org/flagged.org")
;; Set to <your Dropbox root directory>/MobileOrg.
(setq org-mobile-directory "~/Dropbox/MobileOrg")
(setq org-mobile-files org-agenda-files)
```

Org version
Org-mode version 8.2.10 (8.2.10-40-gc763fa-elpa @ /home/nwpwr/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20150518/)

Stable version 8.2.10 (Oct. 2014)

- Also I tried to build from tar.gz nothing changed (Edit: 23.05.2015)

Emacs version

GNU Emacs 24.4.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.14.9) of 2015-03-21 on kissel, modified by Debian

Dropbox files

```
➜ nwpwr@ubuntux  ~/Dropbox/MobileOrg  ls -la
total 48
drwxrwxr-x 2 nwpwr nwpwr 4096 May 21 21:55 .
drwx------ 5 nwpwr nwpwr 4096 May 21 21:15 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nwpwr nwpwr 1413 May 21 21:53 agendas.org
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nwpwr nwpwr  195 May 21 21:53 checksums.dat
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nwpwr nwpwr  278 May 21 21:53 index.org
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nwpwr nwpwr    0 May 21 21:55 mobileorg.org
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nwpwr nwpwr  333 May 21 21:53 OrgCapture.org
```

~/org files

```
drwxrwxr-x  2 nwpwr nwpwr 4096 May 21 21:57 .
drwxr-xr-x 60 nwpwr nwpwr 4096 May 21 22:29 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 nwpwr nwpwr  158 May 21 21:57 flagged.org
-rw-rw-r--  1 nwpwr nwpwr  333 May 21 21:53 OrgCapture.org
```

---

If you use still MobileOrg

What is your

```
Init Defination
Org version
Emacs Version
```

Link the same problem like me but a little bit old compare this time
https://github.com/matburt/mobileorg-android/issues/93

[Official Screencast](http://mobileorg.ncogni.to/screencasts/MobileOrg-Dropbox-OSX/)

**What I tried to fix**

1. I tried the same configuration like screencast still the same problem on Ubuntu (Edit: 23.05.2015)
2. I tried the same configuration like screencast on Debian(virtual machine)(without any config file like init.el) (Edit: 26.05.2015)
3. I tried the same configuration like screencast on Windows 8.1(with md5sum.exe) [Emacs 24.5](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/windows/) (Edit: 26.05.2015)
4. I download [Emacs source code](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs)(Ubuntu) with git, and I compiled nothing changes (Edit: 26.05.2015)
5. http://blog.gabrielsaldana.org/mobileorg-for-android-setup-and-workflow/ (So easy config nobody can make mistake but still doesnt work (Edit: 26.05.2015))
6. During few month, I used it like just a computer to phone sync, yesterday I tried to TODO ---> DONE it's worked(I dont know why) But still it's not usable I am still waiting miracle (Edit 6: 16.11.2015)

Best Regards

Comment: Does `flagged.org` contain information about the problem? It will usually say `EXECUTION FAILED` or something.

Comment: * Not on a heading F(edit:addheadıng) [[olp:OrgCapture.org][OrgCapture.org]]
** Old value

** New value
TODO Phone 
[2015-05-21 Per 21:54]
** End of edit

thats the what is inside pardon I forget and I edit question again

Comment: MobileOrg has seemed flakey; I've had much better luck with [Orgzly](http://www.orgzly.com/)

Comment: No Orgzly does not contain the same features like it. It's not an option. I am still trying to fix that. Thank you for advice :)

Answer (score 1):

do you set you "org-agenda-files" and "org-mobile-files" ?

this is my config

```
 (setq org-agenda-files (list (concat org-directory "agenda.org")
                                         (concat org-directory "todo.org" )
                                         (concat org-directory "note.org")))

(setq org-mobile-files org-agenda-files)
```

when i add note from mobile phone,  i add it to one of them.
then i can see it on my computer.

Comment: Even if I add file like what you say the same problem continue. There is no changes problem. Editing from phone is not possible also with this configs.
can i learn what is your version for them?

Answer (score 1):

this is my config,  tests ok under cygwin ( emacs-nox , 24.4.1 ), windows 7 ( emacs 24.3.1) , and debian 8 ( emacs 24.4..)

```
 (setq org-default-notes-file (concat  org-directory  "capture.org" ))
   (setq org-agenda-files (list (concat org-directory "agenda.org")
                                (concat org-directory "todo.org" )
                                (concat org-directory "note.org")))

  ;;Dropbox setup  Set to the location of your Org files on your local system
  ;; Set to <your Dropbox root directory>/MobileOrg.

   (setq org-mobile-directory "~/Dropbox/mobileorg/" )

     (setq org-mobile-encryption-tempfile (concat org-mobile-directory "orgtmpcrypt") )
     (unless (file-exists-p org-mobile-encryption-tempfile)
       (shell-command (concat "touch "
                              org-mobile-encryption-tempfile)))
```

;; the file "encryption-tempfile " is necessarily, i meet problem without it

```
     (setq org-mobile-files org-agenda-files)
     (setq org-mobile-inbox-for-pull (concat org-directory "from-mobile.org"))
     (unless (file-exists-p org-mobile-inbox-for-pull)
       (shell-command (concat "touch " org-mobile-inbox-for-pull)))
```

orgzly have problem when org-file be changed both on mobile and pc,it can't sync. but mobileorg have the ability to solve it by use "push" or "pull" handle。

Comment: I'll try that later thank you:) and I'll comment again

Answer (score 0):

this is my "checksums.dat", you check your file to see is it contain your org files,  hope it will help you.

```
859f3d092e8678a3ead0ed48c0e8db30  index.org
68b329da9893e34099c7d8ad5cb9c940  mobileorg.org
aa3abdc374ae3f86dac84655be2aedd575522af6  note.org
066da2393d463d596fcc8736eb0fdbefd5a713c3  todo.org
4719448682b631282ff7e49494662085909969e0  agenda.org
546dfe5326a496b49f3448d152474683  agendas.org
```

Comment: I think checksum.dat is different for everybody Its not helpful as I know 
Thank you again.
http://support.sigasi.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/38